# Silverman Prop 1.6

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, kummer-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 1.6 in Silverman's Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. Specifically, I am confused about how he uses the main theorem of Kummer theory. The theorem states:

If a field of characteristic zero contains the $m^{th}$ roots of unity, $\mu_m$, then its maximal abelian extension of exponent $m$, $M/K$, is obtained by adjoining the $m^{th}$ roots of all its elements. i.e. $M = K(a^{1/m} : a \in K)$.

Silverman is using this result to prove if $K$ is a field containing $\mu_m$, and $L/K$ is the maximal abelian sub-extension of $M/K$ that is unramified outside of a set of primes $S$, then $L/K$ is finite. He says that $L$ must be the maximal subfield of $M$ unramified outside of $S$, which makes sense to me. But then I am stuck. He uses a fact (that I will assume for now) that an extension of the form $K(a^{1/m})$ is unramified at prime/place $v$ if and only if $ord_v(a) \equiv 0 \text{ mod } m$. Given this, he says $L$ must be of the form
$$ L = K(a^{1/m} : ord_v(a) \equiv 0 \text{ mod } m),$$
and I don't understand why that's true. Certainly, $K(a^{1/m} : ord_v(a) \equiv 0 \text{ mod } m) \subseteq L \subset M$. But how do we know a subset of the $a^{1/m}$ generate $L$? Is this true of all subfields of $M$?

Comment: It is unclear what is $m$ in the second part. Maybe you meant $L$ is the maximal subextension of $M/K$ unramified outside $S$ ?

Comment: Yes, thanks I meant for L to be defined inside of M. Does that clarify your question about $m$? (It should be the same $m$ as in the first part.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I read the wikipedia page on Kummer theory and I think it answers my question. [According to Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory)/Kummer theory, if $K$ contains the $m^{th}$ roots of unity, any abelian, exponent m extension of K will be generated by $m^{th}$ roots of elements of $K$. Thus $L$ is generated by $m^{th}$ roots of elements of $K$. Then you can use the above fact (that $K(a^{1/m})$ is unramified at prime/place $\nu$ if and only if $ord_\nu(a) \equiv 0$ mod $m$) to get the desired result.

Edit: Also while I'm at it, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440623/when-is-a-non-archimedean-prime-v-of-a-number-field-unramified-in-a-kummer-ext) SE question covers why $K(a^{1/m})$ is unramified $\leftrightarrow$ $ord_\nu(a) \equiv 0$ mod $m$.